# Bootstrap header to compensate for collapsible sidebar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4 and I've created a partially collapsible sidebar which is actually working perfectly for me.

My problem is, I'm trying to add a top header/nav bar that holds the toggle to collapse the sidebar and on the right of the header navbar I want my user icon for logging in and out, etc.

I created a header called #userHeader, which expands the width of the page and houses the toggle (again, this part works) but I used `100vw` for the header and that's too much width because it extends off the page and you can't see the icon.

My question is this: How can I create a responsive header here that always extends the remaining width of the page from the space the sidebar takes up already?

In other words, if it's not collapsed and the sidebar takes up 15% of the page and then once collapsed it takes up 5%, the header would compensate in the way it does now but with the right side always stuck to the right side of the page.

The HTML block in question:

```css
#userHeader {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
}

#userHeader i {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="secondHeader">
  <!--Note: I have no styling for this id yet-->
  <div id="userHeader">
    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class=".btn">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
   </button>
    <i id="user" class="far fa-user-circle fa-2x"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a working codepen, thought I've only kept the most necessary html. All CSS and JS is what I'm using in my page currently:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gKPJgq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this,since you are using bootstrap, grid system documentation may help https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

The width you set is fixed. You may want to try setting max-width or put a '%' as a unit since percentage units are relative to the parent element, or in your case (as i assume) body.

On the other hand, putting sidebar and #userHeader into separate columns may help solve your problem.  Since Bootstraps grid works in 12 column system, giving your sidebar a, (lets say) col-3 class, #userHeader should fill out the rest.

Also, you may want to check out [flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) for overall easier layout positioning and responsiveness.

Comment: This answer seems pretty generic, for a question with a lot of specifics, is it possible to provide a more targeted solution without just links?